# XSL - Calling XSL template from another file is not working

Tags: xml, xslt

As I mentioned in the title of this post, calling XSL template from another file inside another main XSL is not working for me. Here is the preview of my code

-- sample_data.xml -- (Dummy XML data)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

-- sample_xpath.xsl -- (Main XSL that calls XSL template)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:include href="sample_template.xsl"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="*/cd">
            <xsl:call-template name="foo">
                <xsl:with-param name="_title" select="title"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="_artist" select="artist"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

-- sample_template.xsl -- (XSL template)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template name="foo">
        <xsl:param name="_title"/>
        <xsl:param name="_artist"/>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$_title"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$_artist"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your example shows the stylesheet commented out.

Comment: Don't tell us something doesn't work, tell us how it fails.

Comment: @KevinBrown sorry my bad, that shouldn't be commented

Comment: @MichaelKay So just to break it down a little bit, I am using Notepad++ to test this out, with "XML Editor" plugins. Normally when it works it would normally output the result in a new section tab. However, this is not the case when I try to call template from another file. The error that shows is "The XSL stylesheet is not valid. Transformation aborted"

Comment: The problem cannot be reproduced using your (uncommented) code. The error message you quote is not telling much; try a better testing environment. It's possible that the included stylesheet is not in the same directory as the main stylesheet; in such case you should get an error saying something like "unable to load sample_template.xsl". It's also possible that your application does not allow `xsl:include`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k so you are saying that your code works just fine ? What sort of testing environment/platform do you use to test this ? You might be right that my platform may not allowed `xsl:include`

Comment: I use my own testing environment that allows calling various processors from the command line. Your code works fine with libxslt, Xalan and Saxon.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thank you for the information, I will look into those alternatives. Much appreciate it